# Adding more layers decreases accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, mlp

I have my ANN trained on MNIST dataset. Hidden layer has 128 neurons and input layer has 784 neurons. This gave me an accuracy of 94%. However when I added one more layer with 64 neurons in each then the accuracy significantly reduced to 35%. What could be the reason behind this.

Edit : Activation function : sigmoid. 521 epochs.

Comment: What is the activation function you are using?

Comment: @DuttaA sigmoid

Comment: Could you provide both training and test accuracy in both cases

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that by adding more layers, you've added more trainable parameter to your model. You have to train it more. You should consider that `MNIST` data set is a very easy-to-learn dataset. You can have to layers with much less number of neurons in each layer. Try $10$ neurons for each to facilitate the learning process. You can reach to $100%$ accuracy.

Comment: It's also a very small dataset.

Comment: Yes! $50$ thousand is very smal for deep-learning purposes.

Comment: I added 10 neurons in both hidden layers. Trained for 100 epichs and the accuracy is 21%

Comment: Epoch or iteration?

Comment: Epochs..........

Comment: Iterations are the same as number of data

Comment: I guess you are doing something wrong. It is very memory-consuming to load 50 thousand images simultaneously. Please put your code. I've said that due to stating iterations are equal to epochs.

Comment: Making changes to https://github.com/HyTruongSon/Neural-Network-MNIST-CPP     I hope this makes it easier to understand

Comment: Epochs = iterations here. @Media

Comment: There may be something wrong.

Comment: @Media I have posted the same question under username nerd giraffe on stackoverflow. Please take a look at it

Comment: please add the link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case (as I thought previously) is the sigmoid activation function. It suffers from many problems. Out of that your performance decrease is likely due to two reasons:

- [Vanishing Gradient](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-vanishing-gradient-problem)
- High learning rate

NOTE: The link provided for 'Vanishing Gradient' explains beautifully why increasing layers make your network more susceptible to saturation of learning.

The vanishing gradient problem makes sure your Neural Neyt is trapped in a non optimal solution. While the high learning rate ensures that you get trapped in the non optimal solution. In short the high learning rate after a few oscillations will push your network to saturation.

**Solution:**

- Best solution is to use the ReLu activation function, with maybe the last layer as sigmoid.
- Use an adaptive optimizer like AdaGrad, Adam or RMSProp.
- Decrease the learning rate to $10^-6$ to $10^-7$ but to compensate increase the number of epochs to $10^6$ to $10^7$.

Comment: Has nothing to do with this, it's the size of the network compared to the amount of data available.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher what exactly do you mean by size?

Comment: The size of the network (number of layers + number of nodes per layers).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher yes adding a layer makes it more prone to less learning via vanishing gradient, check the link of vanishing gradient...i did not add it my answer because the answer given was great, however I will indicate it in my answer

Comment: I know what a vanishing gradient is... You don't know what OP uses for the training, and the number of epochs is a proof that you didn't read the question.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher what OP uses for the training? what do u mean by that? also how number of epochs indicate what? I am at a loss here..can you explain your stand more clearly

Comment: The number of epochs is 521, not 1 million. And you don't know what kind of optimizer is used. If you need to know, ask as a comment first, same for learning rate.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I am pretty sure the the learning rate is not in the order I provided, second I provided it as a global solution not localised to just the OP's problem...nitpicking to downvote is not something I would not suggest...also the link tells why stacking layers might lead to bad learning, I do not think you checked the link